# Click event on parent not working on child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some square divs in my website that shows text and a big icon.

I'd like a modal to appear when a user clicks on the div, but since the icon is an object, when a user clicks on the div (just the div, not on the icon) the modal shows. When they click on the icon, the click event does not trigger.

This is my JS

```
(function($) {

  $('.cbp-ig-grid li').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var courseSelected = $(this).find('span').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    var bodyContent = $('.full_body_content');

    bodyContent.addClass('BluredBackground');
    bodyContent.before("<div class='selectExamStage'><p>Porfavor escoge que parte del curso deseas practicar</p><div class='ExercisesPartDiv ExercisesPart_1'></div><div class='ExercisesPartDiv ExercisesPart_2'></div><div class='ExercisesPartDiv ExercisesPart_3'></div></div>").slideDown('slow');
    bodyContent.before('<div class="blockDiv"></div>');

    $('.blockDiv').on('click',function(){
      $('.full_body_content').removeClass('BluredBackground');
      $('.selectExamStage').hide('slow', function(){ this.remove(); });
      $(this).hide('slow', function(){ this.remove(); });


        })

    })


})(jQuery);
```

The HTML

```
<ul class='cbp-ig-grid'>
        <li>
            <a>
                <span class='cbp-ig-icon cbp-ig-icon-algebra'>
                    <object type='image/svg+xml' data='" . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  ."/images/Algebra_negro.svg'></object>
                                </span>
                <h3 class='cbp-ig-title'>Álgebra</h3>
                <span class='cbp-ig-category'>Ciencias y Letras</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <span class='cbp-ig-icon cbp-ig-icon-aritmetica'>
                    <object type='image/svg+xml' data='" . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  ."/images/Aritmetica_negro.svg'></object>
                </span>
                <h3 class='cbp-ig-title'>Aritmética</h3>
                <span class='cbp-ig-category'>Ciencias y Letras</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <span class='cbp-ig-icon cbp-ig-icon-geometria'>
                    <object type='image/svg+xml' data='" . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  ."/images/Geometria_negro.svg'></object>
                </span>
                <h3 class='cbp-ig-title'>Geometría</h3>
                <span class='cbp-ig-category'>Ciencias y Letras</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        ...
        ...
```

and the CSS

```
.cbp-ig-grid {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.cbp-ig-grid li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    height: 420px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 0px solid #ddd;
}

/* we are using a combination of borders and box shadows to control the grid lines */
.cbp-ig-grid li:nth-child(-n+3){
    border-top: none;
}

/* anchor style */
.cbp-ig-grid li > a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    color: #47a3da;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}

/* the icon with pseudo class for icon font */
.cbp-ig-icon {
    width: 180px;
    height: 260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.cbp-ig-icon:before {
    font-family: 'besticon';
    font-size: 14em;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Hope someone will help me with this

Comment: why not assign a class and bind your click event to that class?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution but what I want to know is how to pass the trigger to the child and not 'hack' the solution creating more classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your css file

```
object{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

or you can use `<img>` tag instead of `<object>`.

Comment: The object style was enough, why the a display inline-block?

Comment: Object style is sufficient. You can skip the a display inline-block.